# MongoDB/Mongoid: sorting by referenced document's ID

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoid

I have 2 classes in Mongoid: Topic & Post. Topic references many posts.

I want to order topics by post's id descending, so that the most recent post is at the top.

```
@topics = Topic.order_by(:last_message.created_at.desc)
```

This obviously doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way it's to create extra field 'LastMessageCreated' in Topic and save post date after each post and than order topics by 'LastMessageCreated'.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it too.

Comment: It's normal practice to have extra fields for filtering and ordering and searching.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@topics = Topic.desc('posts.created_at')
```

Or

```
@topics = Topic.order_by('posts.created_at',:desc)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This is what it is translated to: find({"topic_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('...')}, {}).sort([])

Answer (score 0):

`Topic.all(sort: [[:created_at, :desc]])`